# Why is my owl carousel autoplay not working?

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

I want to asking about Owl Carousel autoplay.
I have create some html code like this :

```
    <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="img/img1.png" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="img/img2.png" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="img/img3.png" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="img/img4.png" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="img/img5.png" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="img/img6.png" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="img/img7.png" alt="" ></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-clients" src="img/img8.png" alt="" ></div>
    </div>
```

and here's the js file :

```
$(document).ready(function (){
          $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            items:5,
            center:true,
            autoPlay:true,
            autoPlayTimeout:1000,
            autoplaySpeed:3000,
            autoHeight:true,
            autoplayHoverPause:true,
            loop:true,
            // smartSpeed:1000,
            margin:5,
            responsive:{
                480:{
                  items:3,
                  margin:2
                },
                919:{
                    items:4,
                    margin:4
                }
            }
          });
      });
```

but it seem's it didn't working. what's making it wrong? anybody can help?

Comment: Can you create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please create demo of your problem

Comment: Are there spelling case issues?

autoplaySpeed -> autoPlaySpeed?  
autoplayHoverPause -> autoPlayHoverPause?

Answer (score 0):

```
autoplay: true,
```

Instead of

```
autoPlay: true,
```